# How can I make my stroke text compatible with overflow?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-text

I have the following text

```
// Flutter imports:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

@immutable
class StrokeText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final Color color;
  final Color strokeColor;
  final double strokeWidth;
  final TextAlign? textAlign;
  final TextStyle? style;
  final TextOverflow? overflow;

  const StrokeText(
    this.text, {
    Key? key,
    this.color = Colors.white,
    this.strokeColor = Colors.black,
    this.strokeWidth = 1,
    this.textAlign,
    this.style,
    this.overflow,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Text(
          text,
          overflow: overflow,
          textAlign: textAlign,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: style?.fontSize,
            fontWeight: style?.fontWeight,
            fontFamily: style?.fontFamily,
            height: style?.height,
            wordSpacing: style?.wordSpacing,
            overflow: overflow,
            foreground: Paint()
              ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
              ..color = strokeColor
              ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke,
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          text,
          overflow: overflow,
          textAlign: textAlign,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: style?.fontSize,
            fontWeight: style?.fontWeight,
            fontFamily: style?.fontFamily,
            height: style?.height,
            wordSpacing: style?.wordSpacing,
            overflow: overflow,
            foreground: Paint()..color = color,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

But when it overflows, it the stoke seems to be cut off in certain parts

[image]

Where it normally show like this without overflow, which looks good

[image]

Example:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: TestPage(),
    ),
  );
}

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestPage> createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          width: 500,
          height: 500,
          color: Colors.red,
          child: const Center(
            child: StrokeText(
              'ViQAQjlJXlaLeJMusUTNWAdjAkeTzneqAEbbIwCV',
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              strokeWidth: 4.0,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                fontFamily: 'DePixel',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add a parent widget you are using?

Comment: It is not clear how you like to handle overflow, And this widget won’t reproduce the issue until we are aware of the parent widget, in this case consider including how you are using it inside scaffold.

Comment: Provided an example

Comment: If anyone is missing the issue of this question, check first and last character

Comment: The issue is that the stroke visually seems to be cut off on all sides once overflow starts to happen. As the images demonstrate. Could you explain what you meant by check first and last character?

Comment: Yes it gets cut off from all side after getting text height but for first char it gets cut off just from the start point

Answer (score 0):

If you are giving `height` to your `style` then please remove it as of now and check without `height` because `height` is causing issue here.

And if still not working as you want then provide me code where you have used that `StrokeText` `widget`.

Comment: I am not giving a height, provided an example

Answer (score 0):

Is issue is the renderbox of stack is rendered only till the area of the text. You can wrap the stack in StrokeText class with a container and add a margin

```
return Container(
margin : EdgeInsets.all(strokeWidth),
 child: Stack(
 )
)
```

Comment: This does not work

Comment: Also that is not the issue, setting clipBehavior: Clip.none should solve it if that were the case which it does not.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:untitled/stroke_text.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: TestPage(),
    ),
  );
}

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestPage> createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          width: 500,
          height: 500,
          color: Colors.red,
          child: const Center(
            child: StrokeText(
              'ViQAQjlJXlaLeJMusUTNWAdjAkeTzneqAEbbIwCV',
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                fontFamily: 'DePixel',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not work

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
  MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 100,
          child: OutlinedText(
              text: Text('Outlined Text asa asdasd asdasd sa', 
                      style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30,
                       
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  fontFamily: 'DePixel',
                        color: Colors.white,
                        letterSpacing: -0.5
                ),
                         overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                         maxLines: 1,
                      ),
              strokes: [
                  OutlinedTextStroke(
                      color: Colors.black, 
                      width: 3
                  ),
              ],
          ),
        )
      )
    )
  )
);

class OutlinedTextStroke {
  final Color? color;
  final double? width;

  OutlinedTextStroke({this.color, this.width});
}

class OutlinedText extends StatelessWidget {
  final Text? text;
  final List<OutlinedTextStroke>? strokes;

  const OutlinedText({Key? key, this.text, this.strokes}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final children = <Widget>[];
    final list = strokes ?? [];
    double widthSum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      widthSum += list[i].width ?? 0;
      children.add(Text(text?.data ?? '',
          textAlign: text?.textAlign,
                        maxLines: text?.maxLines,
                        overflow: text?.overflow,
          style: (text?.style ?? TextStyle()).copyWith(
              foreground: Paint()
                ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
                ..strokeWidth = widthSum
                ..color = list[i].color ?? Colors.transparent)));
    }

    return Stack(
      children: [...children.reversed, text ?? SizedBox.shrink()],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping the widget with SizedBox